# Dire « Yawn! » quand on s’ennuie ?

Tags: expressions

En anglais se dit des fois « Yawn! » pour montrer qu’on s’ennuie (sarcastiquement).

C’est comme :

*« And then we talked about the new stock and he told me we’re getting new coffee machines and... »*

*« Yaaaawn. I don’t care, Dad. »*

Il y a une phrase comme ça en français ? Ou quelque chose à ce point sarcastique ?

Answer (score 3):

Il y a bien sûr beaucoup de façons d'exprimer l'ennui, mais pas vraiment une qui emploie le mot "bâiller" (*to yawn*).

On peut penser à

> Pfff... Je m'en fiche Papa.
>
> Passionnante ton histoire, Papa (*<- this would be more like an actual sarcasm*)
>
> Tu me rases, Papa (*for a silent version of this, one can also mime being shaved by wiping the back of one's fingers against one's own cheek, as noted by Greg in comments*)
>
> La barbe, Papa
>
> Ça me fait une belle jambe, Papa

Comment: Toujours sur l'image du rasoir, on peut aussi dire "C'est rasoir" ou "La barbe !", ou faire un geste en frottant le revers de de ses doigts contre la joue (à mon sens, ce geste est lié à l'image du rasoir/barbe et n'est pas utilisé dans d'autres langues).

Comment: @Greg merci, ajouté

Comment: Ici, je préfère l'expression *Passionnante ton histoire* (ou simplement *Passionnant !*), qui me semble moins agressive que les autres et convient mieux au contexte. Mais les autres expressions sont parfaitement valides et peuvent convenir à d'autres contextes.